# Pymongo full text search in chinese

Tags: python, mongodb, full-text-search, pymongo

I know Pymongo supports text search feature for many languages e.g. English, French, German..., but it doesn't work for Chinese. Is there a available way to implement Chinese full text search, under the environment of MongoDB 3.4 + Pymongo 3.4 ?

Comment: Yes MongoDB supports ["simplified and traditional chinese"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/text-search-languages/#text-search-languages). Excerpt *"Changed in version 3.2: MongoDB Enterprise includes support for Arabic, Farsi (specifically Dari and Iranian Persian dialects), Urdu, Simplified Chinese, and Traditional Chinese. To support the new languages, the text search feature uses the three-letter language codes defined in ISO 636-3. To enable support for these languages, .."*. But there are some issues [SERVER-18447](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-18447)

Comment: @NeilLunn The webpage said 'MongoDB Enterprise includes support for Arabic, Farsi...' Does that mean I should pay for 'Enterprise' version?

Comment: It means exactly what it says. Yes. If and when that changes I cannot tell you. But I would suggest the feature is added at the request of enterprise customers and therefore may take some time at least to hit a general release. But there is an option. Can you add these in yourself? I believe the code is locked that way from memory, so no.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for your recommendation. I have an indirect way to solve it, which I have posted below as an answer. By far, it can work for me to some extent.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main reason that pymongo free version doesn't support Chinese full text search is that Chinese segmentation is difficult. I have an indirect approach to tackle Chinese full text search by Pymongo. One can finish the segmentation before he store the corpus into MongoDB or search a sentence from MongoDB. The `jieba` module is what I strongly recommends for Chinese segmentation. There is a self-contained simple example, which works for me to some extent.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from pymongo import TEXT
import jieba
client = MongoClient()
dialogs = client['db']['dialogs_zh_fulltext']
d1 = {
    'text_in': '你 早上 吃 的 什么 ?',
    'text_out': '我 吃 的 鸡蛋',
}
d2 = {
    'text_in': '你 今天 准备 去 哪 ?',
    'text_out': '我 要 回家',
}
dialogs.insert_many([d1,d2])
dialogs.create_index([('text_in', TEXT)], default_language='en')
keywords = ' '.join(jieba.lcut('你今天早上去哪了?'))
print('keywords: {}'.format(keywords))
cursor = dialogs.find({'$text': {'$search':keywords}}, {'score':{'$meta':'textScore'}})
for x in cursor.sort([('score', {'$meta':'textScore'})]):
    print(x)
```

OUTPUT:

```
keywords: 你 今天 早上 去 哪 了 ?
{'_id': ObjectId('59673a0d5975ae05e9b27dd8'), 'text_in': '你 今天 准备 去 哪 ?', 'text_out': '我 要 回家', 'score': 2.4}
{'_id': ObjectId('59673a0d5975ae05e9b27dd7'), 'text_in': '你 早上 吃 的 什么 ?', 'text_out': '我 吃 的 鸡蛋', 'score': 1.2}
```